# Filtering image collection based on a custom function Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter, google-earth-engine-python-api

I want to filter image collection based on a custom function Google Earth Engine (GEE) Python API. For example, and this is just an example to make this question tangible.
I want to filter the Sentinel-2 image collection based on the SCL band. The filter should say the following: any image that has at least one pixel equal to 1,2,4, or 6 should be filtered out. So let's say the image collection contains 3 images, and the first image SCL band has the values: 4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5, the second image: 7,7,7,7,7,7,1,4,5, and the third image: 5,5,5,5,5,8,8,8,8. After applying the filter I would expect the image collection to contain only image 1 and image 3.

This is how I generate the image collection:

```
img_collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED").filterDate('2023-11-03','2023-12-03').filterBounds(polygon)
```

From here I'm a bit stuck. I looked at the GEE documentation and tried several times asking chatGPT but could not find an answer. I understand that I need somehow to create a function that will return per image True/False and then map the function over the image collection. I'm not sure if GEE has a function that can count the number of pixels that fit my criteria and based on that filter the images, or if GEE needs first to classify SCL pixels into zeros and ones based on my criteria, and the filter, and in general what is the expression/object such a function should return so that an image will be reduced from the image collection.

Please refer to this example as a general example and not as a Sentinel-2-specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's expensive.

You need to make a histogram of all the pixels in each image (mapped reduceRegion using a frequencyHistogram reducer) and store the results (just the list of values found, not the counts) as a property on each image.  Then filter for the images with the histogram results you want, using filter.listContains.

But... most likely, this is a way to implement what amounts to a bad plan; why do you care if there's other SCL values somewhere else in the image?  Why not just mask off anything that's not a SCL you care about and then use what's left?  (it'll use more "images" but is likely to be way faster).

Comment: For my specific needs, any image that has even one "bad" value is invalid, and I do not want to use this image at all, even if other pixels are "good". Would it be less expensive to save all the SCL values to a local list (i.e., on the client side) and do the filtering on my local machine, then find all the dates with "valid" images, and finally filter the image collection according to a list of valid dates?  BTW, this task is pretty simple with Sentinel-Hub API.

Comment: Depending on the size of your ROI, "all" pixels could be trillions or more, so ... no, I wouldn't try to do it client side.